# Adding a gradient filling according to a given function between two curves

Tags: plotting

Consider the following sample code

```
f1[x_]:=x;
f2[x_]:=2x;
 c[y_]:= Exp[-y];  

Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
     PlotStyle -> {ColorData["SolarColors", 0], ColorData["SolarColors", 1]}]

Plot[c[2 x - x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

I would like to have a filling that fills the area between the two curves `f1[x]`,`f2[x]` by the values of `c[f2[x]-f1[x]]` in the following manner

1. That the values of `c[f1[x]]` and `c[f2[x]]` will be the end values of the colordata.
2. The area in between them will be a gradient fill with the colordata that is normalized according to `c[f2[x]-f1[x]]`

What I want is best presented in the figure

[image]

Comment: 1. It seems that the values of $c(x)$ do not fit between the two curves though. 2. What property of the filling should be influenced by the value of $c(x)$? Should the filling be within the two curves, or from one of the curves to the axis? I think you could perhaps clarify your question a bit.

Comment: @MarcoB. Thanks, I've edited the question and title, hope it is better understood now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
Plot[{f1[x], f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
     ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 
     Blend[{ColorData["SolarColors", 0], ColorData["SolarColors", 1]}, 
     c[(y - f2[x])/(f1[x] - f2[x])]]],
     ColorFunctionScaling -> False
]
```

[image]

It looks better if you normalise $\exp$ to the range $[0,1]$ instead of $[0,e^{-1}]\approx [0,.4]$:

```
c[y_] := (Exp[-y] - Exp[-1])/(1 - Exp[-1])
```

[image]

Comment: you should use `ColorFunctionScaling->False` here (this only works because your scale is 0-1 anyway.)

Comment: @george2079 Thank you, but surely I must be missing something: if I add your option to my code, the figure becomes solid yellow: https://i.imgur.com/jtM7COp.png Do you know why?

Comment: you have the `x` and `y` reversed in the color function, `c[(y - f1[x])/(f2[x] - f1[x])]`

Comment: @george2079 perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `parametricPlot` with `(ColorData["SolarColors"][c@#4] &)` as the `ColorFunction` setting:

```
ParametricPlot[{x, t f1[x] + (1 - t) f2[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> (ColorData["SolarColors"][c@#4] &)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since V 12.2 there is `LinearGradientFilling`:

```
c1 = ColorData["SolarColors", 1];
c2 = ColorData["SolarColors", 0];

Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 FillingStyle -> LinearGradientFilling[{c1, c2}, Bottom],
 PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]

There are many possibilities, f.e.:

```
Plot[{x, 2 x}, {x, 0, 1},
 Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
 FillingStyle -> LinearGradientFilling[{c1, c2}, Right],
 PlotStyle -> None]
```

[image]